# Topology: is it ever good to write $x \in U \in \mathfrak{T}$

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, proof-writing

Sometimes I come across a sentence in my topology book that says,

> let $U$ be an open set that contains $x$

I can't help but write it down as:

> Let $$x \in U \in \mathfrak{T}$$

Is it good to write this?

Comment: It’s perfectly understandable, and many people do write such things, but it’s grammatically incorrect: read literally, it says that the reader is to understand $x$ to be something-or-other, when it’s supposed to let the reader know that $U$ is something-or-other. It’s up to you how much this does or doesn’t bother you.

Comment: The more general expression generally is "a neighborhood $U$ of $x$". In practically all cases is the same.

Comment: This is what I'd put down on scratch paper, but probably never use in any occasion more formal than that. I prefer to say " Let $U$ be an open neighborhood (in $X$) of $x$".

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Does it conflict when people declare that a singleton is open by writing $\{x\} \in \mathfrak{T}$? If I write it like $x \in U \in \mathfrak{T}$, then I might be confusingly saying that $x$ is open....

Comment: @BarackUnchained: No, $x\in U\in\mathfrak{T}$ clearly says that $x$ is an element of an open set $U$, *not* that $x\in\mathfrak{T}$. There’s nothing wrong with writing $\{x\}\in\mathfrak{T}$ to say that $x$ is an isolated point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is much clearer to stipulate that $U$ is an open set.  Expressing it as an element of the topology does not increase the clarity of what you are saying.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing before I saw your remark. And I still think it *after* seeing your remark! (Humm... NCSSM -- I taught 3 years at LSMSA, and I know Dan Teague.)

Comment: I taught there in the math dept for 5 years, then I founded the computer science program.  Are you at U of Iowa?

Comment: I'm not at U of Iowa. Rather, I work (not teaching) in the same city.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might raise eyebrows for those who are new to set theory and topology, but that is precisely why I like this notation. One better get used to certain sets having elements which are sets containing further elements themselves.

---

That said, if you want to “translate”

> Let $U$ be an open set that contains $x$

a better solution in this case might be

> Suppose that $x\in U\in\mathfrak T$.

Answer (score 0):

A set is called open if it is *in* the topology. It's consequently implied, by virtue of $U$ being called "open", that it's in the collection $\frak{T}$. While technically correct, I think you'd be wasting time by writing it, better to just declare it "open."